# Firebase update user data from firebase function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to update user data using firebase function, it's working fine when update user display name. My issue here is below function not updating the user password through firebase function.

```
exports.updateUserPassword = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    try {
        return await authAppAdmin.auth().getUserByEmail(data.email)
            .then((userPassUpdate) => {
                console.log(userPassUpdate.uid);
                return authAppAdmin.auth().updateUser(userPassUpdate.uid,
                    {
                        password: data.newPassword,
                        displayName: data.displayName
                    });
            })
            .catch((error) => console.log(error["message"]));
    } catch (error) {
        return error;
    }
});
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Apart from mixing async/await and then (which is not an error stricto sensu) your code seems correct. Do you get an error?

Comment: @Mises With the Admin SDK you can update a user's password. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin and https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I am not getting any error, I can successfully update displayname of the user, but not the password.

Comment: Are you sure the object you pass to the Callable Function is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following code? I have doubts it will solve your problem but I think we should give a try. If you still get the same problem I'll delete this answer.

It is important that you copy the three first lines and use `admin.auth()...`. Also this code should normally correctly log any error.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.updateUserPassword = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    try {
        const userPassUpdate = await admin.auth().getUserByEmail(data.email)
        console.log(data.newPassword);
        console.log(userPassUpdate.uid);
        await admin.auth().updateUser(
            userPassUpdate.uid,
            {
                password: data.newPassword,
                displayName: data.displayName
            });
        return { result: "OK" }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', JSON.stringify(error)); // See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors
    }
});
```